# Filtering out 'most recent' example record in Rapidminer

Tags: rapidminer

I'm trying to filter an example set of commercial properties in rapidminer. Many of the properties are duplicated because the property transaction history is included in the data table, and many of the properties been sold more than once over the period of the data table. What I want to do is to filter out all but the most recent transaction for each property.

I can't figure out how to filter all but the record with the most recent transaction date. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I just needed some sleep because when I woke up this morning I found what appears to be a simple and embarrassingly obvious solution. 

I found that the 'Remove Duplicates' worked if I sorted the example set by date. That operator saves the first occurrence of an example  within an example set which, if sorted by date, is the most recent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post a standalone reproducible example that includes data to show what you have tried so far.

Without this, the general advice might be along these lines. Use the `Aggregate` operator to find the maximum date for a given property then use the `Join` operator to inner join the original example set with the example set containing maxima.

Here's a toy example using the Iris data set that might be applicable in your case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><process version="7.4.000">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="7.4.000" expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="retrieve" compatibility="7.4.000" expanded="true" height="68" name="Retrieve Iris" width="90" x="112" y="187">
        <parameter key="repository_entry" value="//Samples/data/Iris"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="aggregate" compatibility="7.4.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Aggregate" width="90" x="313" y="187">
        <list key="aggregation_attributes">
          <parameter key="a1" value="maximum"/>
        </list>
        <parameter key="group_by_attributes" value="label"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="join" compatibility="7.4.000" expanded="true" height="82" name="Join" width="90" x="514" y="187">
        <parameter key="use_id_attribute_as_key" value="false"/>
        <list key="key_attributes">
          <parameter key="label" value="label"/>
          <parameter key="a1" value="maximum(a1)"/>
        </list>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Retrieve Iris" from_port="output" to_op="Aggregate" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Aggregate" from_port="example set output" to_op="Join" to_port="right"/>
      <connect from_op="Aggregate" from_port="original" to_op="Join" to_port="left"/>
      <connect from_op="Join" from_port="join" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```